# Search Engine Developement using MySQL relevancy, not working on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search-engine

i'm working on search engine developement.
I'm kinda struggling with an SQL/PHP request. I'm trying to get the highest relevancy score from a search query. It works perfectly on SQL, but not at all on PHP, neither on localhost nor online (while the source code is generated by phpmyadmin itself).

```
    $connect = mysqli_connect('a', 'b','c','d');    
    $sql1 = "SELECT job, MATCH (job)  AGAINST (\'sales representative\' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM general_comp ORDER BY score DESC limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1); 

    echo $result;
```

Obviously SQL connection works, since other requests are working very well.
Any idea ?

Source = https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: You have to fetch from the result. `$result` is just a resource.

Comment: So what happens instead of it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [fetch the results](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) from the resource `$result`:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('a', 'b','c','d');    
$sql1 = "SELECT job, MATCH (job)  AGAINST (\'sales representative\' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM general_comp ORDER BY score DESC limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! This helped a lot. However i encountered another issue which was related to the query \'sales representative\' which should be 'sales representative' ! Thanks @Jay